# How to convert column in date format with "Date" Data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-formatting

I am using SQL Server 2017. I am trying to convert one column's values into a date format like `DDMMYY`. I want to keep the same data type as `DATE`.

Using the `CONVERT` and `FORMAT` functions, it returns `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR`.

How can I do this conversion?

Comment: `DATE` has no intrinsic formatting. It is displayed according to however the client wishes to display it. If you want to have a column that displays it with a certain fixed formatting, use a view or computed column and the `FORMAT` function. If you have an existing client that fails to display a `DATE` value the way you want it, that's the problem of the client, not the database.

Comment: Personally I'd use `CONVERT` and a style code rather than `FORMAT`. `FORMAT` is a very slow function, especially when compared to `CONVERT`. If the specific style you want doesn't have a code, you may need to add a `REPLACE`, but it'll be be much faster.

Comment: i want to keep same data type as date, like oracle has to_date function it converts date without changing data type

Comment: If you want to convert a *string* of format `DDMMYY` to a `DATE`, that's the opposite problem. For that, you need to manipulate the string so it matches a format `CONVERT` or `PARSE` will accept, e.g. `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF('010203', 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/'), 3)`.